# BAS installation and bayes.outlier function question

Tags: r, bayesian, cran

I’m trying to install [the R library BAS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BAS/index.html), but I get the error message:

> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘BAS’

It’s using binary 1.4.7 and source 1.5.1. And `library(BAS)` works - no error message. But I can’t use the function `Bayes.outlier`, even after I install the BAS package.

**Is the package not really installed?  Why is the function call not working?**

I already have MASS installed.

Comment: It appears you already have 1.4.7 installed, which is why `library(BAS)` works. But the method `Bayes.outlier` was added only in version 1.4.8, which is why that method doesn't work for you.  You must install at least that version, such as 1.5.1, as you've tried.  In order for us to help you with the installation, you must provide the complete output of the installation messages, which should include more specific details as to why the compilation failed.